# Need an emulator for PS/2 mouse port

Tags: mouse, emulator, ibm-ps2

Is there any emulator that allows to treat all non-PS/2 mouse activities as if I had one? I.e. if I have a usb mouse but it could be reached by interacting with PS/2 port.

Comment: To what end would you want this? An answer to that question might be helpful when trying to find a solution that fits your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/input/mice` is a multiplex device that receives all events from all mice, PS/2 or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a virtual machine of some sort would help?

Answer (score 1):

Windows does this for you, so I am not sure what you are getting at.  If you need a hardware solution, you might try a simple PS/2 to USB adapter.  It doesn't actually adapt the signals... just the plug.  Most mice (Microsoft mice in particular) support the PS/2 protocol natively and automatically switch to it when attached to a PS/2 host.

[image]